# PHPSECLIB and SSH2

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, ssh2

I have been looking for a solution on how I could use `php` to establish a connection to a remote server and execute commands. Researching has brought two solutions to my attention; `phpseclib` and `ssh2`. I will try and keep my questions from turning this into a comparison post. From what I can tell they are both widely used solutions. `ssh2` is a php extension while `phpseclib` is a pure php library. It seems that you can also use `phpseclib` in conjunction with `ssh2`. I would much prefer to avoid needing to install an extension so I am more inclined to use `phpseclib`. However I do have some concerns.

`ssh2` has direct documentation with `php` does this mean it is a better solution to use?

Most of the posts I see regarding `phpseclib` are several years old, is this still a "modern-ish" solution?

`phpseclib` ([found here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html)) says it was built for compatability with `php 4` with `2.0` being geared towards `php 5`. Is this an acceptable solution to those working with `php 7`?

Here is an example using an `RSA key` to establish a `ssh` connection with `phpseclib 2.0`

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$ssh = new SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$key = new RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
```

I am still fairly new to `ssh` but if I understand the above correctly, so long as the remote server has a `.pub` key I can simply supply my connection with my local private key (and user) and I should be able to connect? Does the public key need to be somewhere specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpseclib 1.0, in theory, works on PHP 4.4, but phpseclib 2.0 requires PHP 5.3+. 3.0 requires 5.6+. All versions of phpseclib work all the way through PHP 7.4, as can be seen on the Travis CI test results:

https://travis-ci.org/github/phpseclib/phpseclib

(older versions of PHP aren't unit tested because Travis CI doesn't support them; Docker containers could be used but yeh)

> I am still fairly new to `ssh` but if I understand the above correctly, so long as the remote server has a `.pub` key I can simply supply my connection with my local private key (and user) and I should be able to connect? Does the public key need to be somewhere specific?

Well with OpenSSH server the public key would need to live in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. On the client end of things all you really need is the private key. The public key can be extracted from the private key.